# Radius of a largest circle inscribed under $y=\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n}$, closed form

Tags: geometry, polynomials, optimization, systems-of-equations, lagrange-multiplier

The curve $y=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ has an obvious connection to circles, because it's the derivative of the arctangent function.

Besides, if we inscribe a circle under it, its radius is exactly $R=\frac{1}{2}$, so it takes exactly one fourth of the full area under the curve.

[image]

Actually, I don't know an easy way to find $R$ even in this simple case. So, let's consider how I solve the more general problem.

> Find the largest circle fitting between the curve $y=y (x)$ and the line $y=0$
>
> $$y(x)=\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n}~~~~~~ n=1,2,3,\dots$$

The distance from the circle origin $(0,R)$ to the curve is the minimum of a function:

$$s(x)=\sqrt{x^2+\left(R-\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n} \right)^2}$$

$$s(x)'=0$$

The condition for the inscribed circle is $s(x)=R$.

Let's denote:

$$t=1+x^2$$

Then from the above we obtain the system of equations:

> $$t^{2n+1}+2n~R~t^n-2n=0$$
>
> $$t^{2n+1}-t^{2n}-2~R~t^n+1=0$$

This is how I got the solution for $n=1$ (using Mathematica). Other solutions do not have obvious closed forms. Here are the numerical roots I've got with Mathematica:

$$R_2=0.4735710971151933$$

[image]

$$R_3=0.4401444298014721$$

$$R_4=0.41216506385826285$$

And so on.

The questions I ask:

> Can there be closed forms for $R$ for $n \neq 1$? How to find them?
>
> Is there an easier way to find $R$? At least for some $n$?

**Edit**

The most simple equation for $t$, as far as I can see, is:

> $$(n+1)~t^{2n+1}-n~t^{2n}-n=0$$

I think I might ask a separate question about this equation. It's easy to solve by Newton-Raphson, but can it have closed form solutions for any $n$?

Comment: you are searching for the greatest circle inscribed between the curve $y = \frac{1}{1+(x^2)^n}$ and $y =0$. for $n = 1$, to prove that the circle of radius $1/4$ with center $(0,1/4)$ is the solution, you have to show that $\frac{1}{1+x^2}\ge \frac14 + \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{4}$ for $|x| < 1/4$. actually, your drawings show it is true for $\epsilon < |x| < 1/4$, hence you only have to show that it is true in the neighborhood of $x= 0$, i.e. that $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left[\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right]_{x= 0} > \frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left[\frac14 + \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{4}\right]_{x= 0}$

Comment: more generally (because the LHS and RHS are even functions of $x$) that $\frac{d^{2m}}{dx^{2m}}\left[\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right]_{x= 0} = \frac{d^{2m}}{dx^{2m}}\left[\frac14 + \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{4}\right]_{x= 0}$ for $0 \le m < k$  and that $\frac{d^{2k}}{dx^{2k}}\left[\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right]_{x= 0} > \frac{d^{2k}}{dx^{2k}}\left[\frac14 + \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{4}\right]_{x= 0}$

Comment: @user1952009, the function in your  first comment is not the same as mine.

Comment: I won't be surprised if it cannot be solved algebraically for $n \geq 2$. Indeed, we need to solve $$t^{2n+2} + nt^{2n+1} - nt^{2n} - 2nt + n = 0$$ on $[1, \infty)$. It is easy to prove that this has a unique zero on $[1, \infty)$ which in fact lies on $[1, 2]$, and when $n = 1$ it is exactly 1. But even for $n = 2$, this gives a polynomial of degree 6...

Comment: @SangchulLee, the relevant equation has degree $2n+1$, see the last edit

Comment: Yes, you are right. I made a small mistake when deriving the system of equations independently. Now I got the same equation as you. But the conclusion above remains still true except that we have degree 5 polynomial $3t^5 - 2t^4 - 2$ for $n = 2$. I checked with Magma calculator that this polynomial has Galois group $S_5$, which means that it is not solvable.

Comment: @SangchulLee, could trigonometric solution be possible though?

Comment: I am not sure, and given that I could not find any reference to it, I think it is not possible. (And this is possibly because there are not much quintic polynomials related to triginometric functions and thus they are not capable of representing arbitrary [Bring-Jerrard normal form](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical#Bring.E2.80.93Jerrard_normal_form).) According to the wikipedia article, there are formulas using either Bring radicals or elliptic functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to find tangent points and the circle of contact for given $n$  using the conventional and *classical* Lagrangian multiplier method. The circle can be the object, and given curve the constraint function or vice-versa. A sort of non-linear programming in Operations Research.

Obtained the same contact radii values for each $n$ as the OP.

$R = \lambda $ parameter circles with x-axis tangent at origin are

$$ F = x^2 + (y-\lambda)^2 = x^2 +y^2 -2 y \lambda = 0 \tag{1} $$

$$ y = 1/(1+x^2)^n ;\, \rightarrow G = y (1+x^2)^n - 1 =0 \tag{2} $$

We have a constant Lagrange multiplier $$ \frac{F_x}{F_y}= \frac{G_x}{G_y} = C, \; \tag{3} $$

which after algebraic simplification yields the required link relation:

$$ 2 n y (y-x) = ( 1 + x^2) \; \tag{4} $$

Solving together (1), (2) and (4) we get $ x,y, \lambda = R $  that allow the curves and maximum radius contacts to be sketched as follows for $n = 1,3,6,20.$

The radius cannot be fully expressed in closed form , but only as an *algebraic number* in a *field* given from *Mathematica* for $ n\ne 1 $ example:

```
    n=3, \; \lambda = R =  AlgebraicNumber[
    Root[-8192 + 10240 #1^2 + 9984 #1^4 + 5120 #1^6 + 1520 #1^8 + 
    264 #1^10 + 25 #1^12 + #1^14 &, 2], {1/6, 0, 5/12, 0, 1/4, 0, 11/
    192, 0, 7/1536, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}]
```

EDIT 1
(deleted)

[image: LM_problem_Curve_n & Circles]

Comment: No, please see the picture for $n=2$ in my question. It has nothing to do with the radius of curvature

Comment: Please state $how$ the circle is inscribed under the curve.

Comment: The largest circle between y (x) and 0

Comment: What would you recommend to read about Lagrange multiplier method? I'm interested in other problems about filling curves with circles, and they get very cumbersome with the methods I use

Comment: Yes, I noted it, so I tried to emphasize that it is classical. Available on net. Just find simple examples like maximum area for given perimeter of a rectangle exercise to begin with and follow procedure I outlined. It is easy. But a bit of practice as usual to get the feel..

Comment: Yes, I noted it, so I tried to emphasize that it is classical. Available on net. Just find simple examples like maximum area for given perimeter of a rectangle exercise to begin with and follow procedure I outlined. It is easy. But a bit of practice needed as usual to get the feel.. To be honest I took time to realize the known LM is the way to go.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the interest. By the way, am I correct that the inflection points are $\pm 1/\sqrt{2n+1}$?

Comment: I don't think it does. At least for $n=1$, $x=\pm 1/\sqrt{3}$ doesn't lie on the circle. For $n=2$ it's not true either

Comment: That is correct, you can verify by twice differentiating. But it does not touch here, as can be seen for large $n$, as also you noted, I shall delete that part.

Answer (score 1):

The radius of curvature of a function $f(x)$ is

$$ \rho =- \frac{ \left( 1 + \left(\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}x}f(x)\right)^2 \right)^\frac{3}{2} } { \frac{{\rm d}^2}{{\rm d}x^2} f(x) } $$

<sub>NOTE: If the curve is given implicitly then $$\rho = \frac{ (x'^2+y'^2)^\frac{3}{2}}{y' x'' - y'' x'}$$</sub>

**Case 1**

Consider $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$

$$ \rho = -\frac{ \left(1+\frac{4 x^2}{(1+x^2)^4} \right)^\frac{3}{2}} { \frac{2(3 x^2-1)}{(1+x^2)^3} } $$

and for $x=0$ the circle is $\rho =\frac{1}{2}$ as you expect.

**Case 2**

Consider $f(x) = \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n}$

The radius of curvature is

$$ \rho = \frac{ \left( 4 n^2 x^2 + (1+x^2)^{2(n+1)}\right)^\frac{3}{2} }{ \tfrac{2 n (1-x^2 (2n+1))}{(1+x^2)^{-(2n+1)}}} $$

and for $x=0$ the curvature is simply ${\rho = \frac{1}{2n}}$

---

Now the circle is going to be tangent to the curve (one of the curvature circles) and its center is going to be located at

$$ x_c = x - \frac{ y' (1+y'^2)}{y''} \\ y_c = y + \frac{1+y'^2}{y''} $$

<sub>here $y' = \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}x} f(x)$ and $y'' = \frac{{\rm d}^2}{{\rm d}x^2} f(x)$</sub>

For the circle to be tangent to $y=0$, its center has to be at $y_c = \rho$ or

$$ y + \frac{1+y'^2}{y''} = - \frac{(1+y'^2)^\frac{3}{2}}{y''} $$

For $y=\tfrac{1}{1+x^2}$ my *CAS* says the solution (besides $x=0$) is the roots of

$$ 2 x^{16} + 15 x^{14} + 48 x^{12} + 97 x^{10} + 126 x^8+81 x^6-20 x^4 -33 x^2 = 12$$

$ x = 0.759119999241623 $ or $\rho = 4.32460278011942$, but that ends up being a circle over the curve.

---

For the general case of $y = \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n}$ the equation to be solved is

$$ \left( (1+x^2)^{2(n+1)} + 4 n^2 x^2\right)^\frac{3}{2} + (1+x^2)^{3(n+1)} + 2 n ( 1+x^2)^{n+1} \left( 4 n x^2 + x^2 -1 \right) = 0 $$

Comment: Have you looked at the second graph in my question? It's not radius of curvature that I want.

Comment: So you have to find the curvature circle that is tangent to $y=0$. The center of the circle is located at $$(x,y)-\rho \frac{(-y',x')}{\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}}$$. You need to find the $x$ coordinates which makes the $y$ position of the circle equal to $\rho$.

Comment: See edit in answer now. Sorry for the confusion.